# Accessing hidden columns of jquery datatables when pagination is on

Tags: jquery, datatables

My datatable loads the data in almost 5 pages. I am able to access the hidden columns in the first page. But when i click on the rows in the next pages, the click event isn't getting caught. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dataobjects").dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aoColumns": [ 
                    /* Client */   null,
                    /* Check */  null,
                    /* Desc */    null,
                    /* System Use(in %) */   null,
                    /* Valid */  null,
                    /* Result */    null,
                    /* TimeStamp */    null,
                    /* Facts */ { "bSearchable": false,
                                     "bVisible":    false },

                ]
    });

    oTable = $('#dataobjects').dataTable( );


    $("#dataobjects tbody tr").click( function( e ) {

        if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        } else {
            oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');

            // Get the data from the selected row
            var fid= oTable.fnGetData( this, 7 );
            alert("Output: " + fid);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tr elements do not exist until you reach the next pages; try using event delegation on the table element:

```
$("#dataobjects").on('click', 'tbody tr', function( e ) {

    if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
    } else {
        oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
        $(this).addClass('row_selected');

        // Get the data from the selected row
        var fid= oTable.fnGetData( this, 7 );
        alert("Output: " + fid);
    }
});
```